# SQL запрос, создающий строчку и возвращающий её id

Tags: mysql, sql

Здравствуйте. Есть некая бд, в которой нужно создать новую строчку.

Сейчас я делаю это с помощью двух запросов, первый создаёт, а второй извлекает:

```
INSERT INTO positions (title) VALUES ('title')

SELECT id FROM positions WHERE title='title'
```

Но это, естественно, неправильно, так как в случае двух одинаковых `title` выдаст два `id`.

Как сделать один запрос, который создавал бы строчку, а потом возвращал её `id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cмотри  `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. Есть и для php такая функция

Comment: Но это ведь будет последний добавленный во всю базу!?

Comment: В таблицу, и то если id AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: всё разобрался, спасибо)

Comment: не за что)

Там еще есть особенности у этой функции - при множественной вставке, если id  AUTO_INCREMENT, но вы жестко вставили значение поля. В общем, погуглите - лишним не будет.